# SQL Multiple record : Time Scheduler

Tags: sql, scheduler, multiple-records

I have problem about combining tables in store procedure.
Note : field "Time" is varchar
First table (tbTime)

```
Time
08:00:00
08:30:00
09:00:00
09:30:00
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:30:00
13:00:00
13:30:00
14:00:00
14:30:00
15:00:00
15:30:00
16:00:00
16:30:00
17:00:00
17:30:00
18:00:00
18:30:00
19:00:00
19:30:00
20:00:00
```

Second table (tbClassRsv)

```
select * from tbclassrsv where transdate='2014-02-05 00:00:00' and status<>'DEL'

transDate    time       until    status  studentCode  tutor   class    description  userID
2014-02-05   16:48:14   17:48:14 OPN     ET-7201      ET-444  ROOM 01  try          ADMIN
```

I want the result with condition schedule like this

```
Time       Student
08:00:00   -
08:30:00   -
09:00:00   -
09:30:00   -
10:00:00   -
10:30:00   -
11:00:00   -
11:30:00   -
12:00:00   -
12:30:00   -
13:00:00   -
13:30:00   -
14:00:00   -
14:30:00   -
15:00:00   -
15:30:00   -
16:00:00   -
16:30:00   ET-7201
17:00:00   ET-7201
17:30:00   ET-7201
18:00:00   ET-7201
18:30:00   -
19:00:00   -
19:30:00   -
20:00:00   -
```

Thanks for reading or answer ^_^

## GBU

I`ve tried this

```
select t.time, 
isnull(
(select c.studentCode 
from tbclassrsv c 
where c.transdate='2014-02-05 00:00:00' 
and c.class='ROOM 01'
and c.status<>'DEL' 
and t.time>=c.time 
and t.time<=c.until
),'-') [Student]
```

The result is....

```
Time       Student
08:00:00   -
08:30:00   -
09:00:00   -
09:30:00   -
10:00:00   -
10:30:00   -
11:00:00   -
11:30:00   -
12:00:00   -
12:30:00   -
13:00:00   -
13:30:00   -
14:00:00   -
14:30:00   -
15:00:00   -
15:30:00   -
16:00:00   -
16:30:00   -
17:00:00   ET-7201
17:30:00   ET-7201
18:00:00   -
18:30:00   -
19:00:00   -
19:30:00   -
20:00:00   -
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. you were not converting your varchar times to datetime so that your time comparisons would work.

```
select t.time, 
isnull(
(select c.studentCode 
from tbClassRsv c 
where c.transdate='2014-02-05 00:00:00' 
and c.class='ROOM 01'
and c.status<>'DEL' 
and DateAdd(MINUTE, 30, Convert(datetime, t.time))>= Convert(datetime, c.time) 
and Convert(datetime, t.time) <= Convert(datetime, c.until)
),'-') from [tbTime] t
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is round `c.time` down to the nearest 30 minutes interval, and round `c.until` up to the nearest interval. This way your `where` clause will have the correct range.

To do the rounding you will need to convert the times to `datetime` which you can do like so:

```
CAST(CONVERT(varchar,THE_TIME_AS_VARCHAR,121) AS datetime)
```

Then you can round down to the nearest 30 minutes like so:

```
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, THE_TIME_AS_DATETIME)/30*30, 0)
```

And round up like so:

```
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 30, THE_TIME_AS_DATETIME)/30*30, 0)
```

Applying all that to your existing code would give you this:

```
select t.time, 
isnull(
(select c.studentCode 
    from tbclassrsv c 
    where c.transdate='2014-02-05 00:00:00' 
    and c.class='ROOM 01'
    and c.status<>'DEL' 
    and t.time>= DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, CAST(CONVERT(varchar,c.time,121) AS datetime))/30*30, 0) 
    and t.time<= DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 30, CAST(CONVERT(varchar,c.until,121) AS datetime))/30*30, 0)
),'-') [Student]
```